# SSRS report sometimes does not work for SharePoint visitors with read permission

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, user-permissions

It seems like our SSRS report in SharePoint has some kinds of problems for the users with Read permission.

From time to time, they can view the report, but half of the times they have to enter their credentials several times to get the updated data.

Anyone knows how to solve this kind of problem, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the way you store the credentials for the report. For example, if the report developer uses their personal credentials when creating the report, the viewers will not have permission to run it. To ensure this doesn't happen, set the report to use a shared data source that has the credentials stored in it.

1. Set up a shared data source with saved credentials. Preferably, an admin ID where the password doesn't change.
2. In SharePoint go to "Manage Data Sources" for the report.
3. Click on the data source name to edit it.
4. Select "Shared data source" and select the data source you created.

When developing reports, start by selecting this shared data source. You can still authenticate with personal credentials to run queries during design, but it will use the saved credentials when viewers access the report through SharePoint.